# How select rows by column from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have such problem:

**Table 1** (for ex. products)

```
id, title, price
```

**Table 2** (for ex. variants of products)

```
id, f_id_from_table_1, title, price
```

How can I select rows during price limit (price >= ? AND price <= ?) from **table 2** if price is set there, else from **table 1** if not. What is best practise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, mate:

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.title,
    COALESCE(p.price, p_2.price) 'price'
FROM
    product p
    INNER JOIN product p_2 ON p_2.f_id_from_table_1 = p.id
WHERE
    COALESCE(p.price, p_2.price) BETWEEN ? AND ?;
```

- This solution is when either of the table contains **NULL** and the other one has the value.
- If the default value of the field is **NOT NULL**, then you need to replace the *COALESCE(p.price, p_2.price)* with an *IF(p.price = 0, p_2.price, p.price)*

Answer (score 0):

I'd join then on `id` = `f_id_from_table1` and then add a column in resultset with `IF(tbale2.price >= ? AND table2.price <=?, table2.title, table1.title)`. So it would look like:

```
SELECT *, IF(tbale2.price >= ? AND table2.price <=?, table2.title, table1.title) AS res
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.f_id_from_table_1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE WHEN` and `COALESCE` for your practice.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN t1.price is null THEN t2.title ELSE t1.title END title, 
    COALESCE(t1.price, t2.price) price
FROM table1 as t1 
    LEFT JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.id = t2.table1_id

WHERE 
    CASE WHEN t1.price is null 
    THEN (t2.price >= ? AND t2.price <= ?) 
    ELSE (t1.price >= ? AND t1.price <= ?) END
```

btw, your question is not clear. ^_^